# Enterprise Keywords required in Publishing page

Tags: publishing-page, keyword

I have added the enterprise keyword column to my custom content type that is tied to a publishing page. It works fine editing and publish pages based on this layout  unless I set the keyword column to be required. If I do this I get an error message when pressing the Publish action stating "You must fill out all required properties before completing this action." and then I get transfered to edit properties for the page. It works fine if I save the page first and then publish it.

The control on my page layout looks like this:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
  <Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl ID="TaxonomyFieldControl" FieldName="TaxKeyword" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Have someone stumbled upon this problem before?

Comment: Found this exact same issue, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No we haven't found a solution for this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a solution here:
http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/what-about-you-must-fill-out-all-required-properties-before-completing-this-action-when-publishing-a-page/

The solution requires a custom control on the page, the code is provided in the post.

Regards, Anita

Comment: Please do provide more details to your answer here, it's preferable if your answer is stand-alone from your blog post.